# Java different function return types

Tags: java, oop, function, return, return-type

In a tutorial for java programming, I saw this example:

```
public ClassName open()
{
    code....
}
```

I'm a little bit confused to use the a class name. I'm used to create method like this:

```
public void open()
{
    code...
}
```

Could some explain? Thanks!

Comment: Returning an object from a function that otherwise could return void is useful for a technique [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `void` function returns nothing while the first example returns a `ClassName` object.

For example:

```
public int getInt() {
    return 1;
}
```

In this example an integer is returned. Therefore the method must define what type of object it will return.

Or in your case, what could make sense is the following:

```
public User getLoggedInUser() {
    User user = SomeDeviceClass.getLoggedInUser();
    return user;
}
```

Reading material: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 1):

In that tutorial, the programer must be returning any object of class as `ClassName` will be the return type.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function maybe the object of the class.

```
    public ClassName open()
    {
       ClassName obj;
.
.
.
.
       return obj;
    }
```